# Why voice records are not saved in mp3 format?

Tags: voice-recording

This is not particularly an android related question. All the phones I have used so far, don't record voice in mp3 format. Is it a limitation of the phones? Is there any benefit in recording voice in other formats than mp3? I really don't get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, MP3 is a **Compressed audio file format**, which means some details of Audio will be deleted to reduce the size. If you record your audio in MP3, **the quality will be low than recording in Other  formats** such as ogg or aac.

Hardware is not a limitation. Recorded audio can be converted into any other format using simple software.
Note: Now-a-days many applications in Playstore which can record directly in MP3.

Comment: Ogg Vorbis and AAC are also lossy compression formats, like MP3.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers MP3 also requires some CPU, not a lot by today's standards, but enough to make a difference especially when in the background with other applications competing for CPU time.